# Get only tweets which are retweeted by users and mentions

Tags: twitter

Here I am trying to get user's retweets:

**Goal: To get the retweets of user for last one month**

I already tried similar threads here is my try.

```
    session_start();
    require_once('twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php');
    require_once('config.php');

    if (empty($_SESSION['access_token']) || empty($_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token']) || empty($_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token_secret'])) {
        header('Location: ./clearsessions.php');
    }
    $access_token = $_SESSION['access_token'];
    $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);
    $content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');

$tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$twitteruser."&count=".$notweets);
//var_dump($tweets);

        foreach ($tweets as $item)
        {
                echo $item->text;
                echo "<br/>";
                $tweet = $item->text;
                $insertQuery1 = "INSERT INTO user_tweets (`id`,`name`,`tweet`,`date`) VALUES ('".$id."','".$name."','".$tweet."','".$date."')";
                if (!mysqli_query($con,$insertQuery1))
                {
                        //die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
                }
        }
```

Which gives messed json response where I can not extracts retweets.

Here is another try:

```
$tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweets_of_me.json?screen_name=".$twitteruser.");
```

Which gives not result.

One more try:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitterapi&count=2&include_rts=true
```

which also gives no result.

Please not, my account has some tweets which I have retweeted

Comment: You need oauth based authentication to connect to twitter APIs. I don't see that in your code unless you've parsed that out for readability?

Comment: @Visha: I already did auth process. Let me update the code

Comment: Are you trying to get what the authenticating user retweets from his timeline?

Comment: Have you tried the last call you posted without the screen_name since that would default to the authenticating user? Also, please try to use count=200. The "retweeted" boolean would indicate if authenticating user retweeted something. Also, a retweet is identified by the presence of "retweeted_status", which contains the original tweet.